# How to install snap on CentOS 7?

Tags: snap

Can't find any document shows how to install snap on CentOS 7. There's no document for build from source either.

Does anyone here have any experience on it?

Comment: I know the topic looks off-topic here. But I was redirect here by [snapcraft.io](http://snapcraft.io/community). Here is the only place can ask question in the "Learn more" session at the bottom of that page.

Comment: Are you still looking for information about this? If the Fedora instructions on [the installation page](http://snapcraft.io/docs/core/install) don't work and you cannot adapt them, then you might ask (with full details of what you've tried and where you've looked) on [unix.se], where this would be on-topic. If you decided to do this, and you post a comment here with a link to your question and also ping me in it (include @EliahKagan in the comment), then I'll be notified and I'll go to the question and see if I can help figure it out. This interests me as well.